# Как изменить название окна программы в Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Хочу поменять название окна программы с MainWindow на своё. Уже неоднократно менял названия с помощью windowTitle. Меняю так и в этот раз, но название не изменяется. Как было MainWindow так и осталось. Как быть в таком случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте функцию [void setWindowTitle(const QString &)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowTitle-prop):

```
setWindowTitle("New Title!")
```

Код:

```
...

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow mw;
    mw.setWindowTitle("New Title!");
    mw.show();    

    return app.exec();
}
```